# Typescript typecast with D3.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I'm using the example D3 graph shown [**here**](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/a73f9af9ccd9ef901a0c33c624096049). I have the following data object declared here:

```
interface ID3Data {
  age: string,
  population: number
}

const data: ID3Data[] = [
  { age: "<5", population: 2704659 },
  { age: "5-13", population: 4499890 }
]
```

and then being consumed in the following:

```
const pie = d3.pie()
              .value(function(d: any) { return d.population; });

const arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
             .data(pie(data)) // ->>> Specifically this part of the code
```

Which produces this error:

```
TypeScript error: Argument of type 'ID3Data[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(number | { valueOf(): number; })[]'.
  Type 'ID3Data' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
    Type 'ID3Data' is not assignable to type '{ valueOf(): number; }'.
      Types of property 'valueOf' are incompatible.
        Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
          Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2345
```

Since it's apparent that `d3.pie().value()` consumes a very specific type of input data, what am I doing wrong that's receiving the compilation error? Since D3's value function is specific to it's library... is it something that I can override in my typescript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problematic code:

```
const pie = d3.pie()
              .value(function(d: any) { return d.population; });
```

Since you did not specify the type of the data you are going to pass to the generator the TypeScript compiler will use the following [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-shape/index.d.ts#L621):

```
export function pie(): Pie<any, number | { valueOf(): number }>;
```

That results in the error you witnessed because your type `ID3Data` obviously does not match `number | { valueOf(): number }`.

Fortunately, this can easily be cured by using generics to pass the correct type of data while creating the generator:

```
const pie = d3.pie<ID3Data>()
  .value(function(d) { return d.population; });   // Do not use any for the parameter!
```

This will have the compiler use the following [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-shape/index.d.ts#L630) instead:

```
export function pie<Datum>(): Pie<any, Datum>;
```

As you can see the type `Datum` is now passed on to the [`Pie` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-shape/index.d.ts#L428) type.